# Array of Array to Array of object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to convert array of array to array of object

```
$data=array(
    ["GOA518232","20190301","2019-03-01","shantnu kumar","20000","12","20000","Upward Term Loan","","","Indiabulls Consumer Finance Limited"],
    ["GOA473214","20190304","2019-03-04","KANNAN M KANNAN","25000","12","18000","Upward Term Loan","","","Gestamp Automotive Chennai Pvt Ltd"],
    ["GOA441862","20190308","2019-03-08","veeru biradar","25000","12","17400","Upward Term Loan","","","Tequnic Control Facility Management"],
    ["GOA291263","20190308","2019-03-08","pavan guptha","50000","24","22000","Upward Term Loan","","","Hcl Technologies Limited"]
);
```

Output expected

```
[
    {"GOA518232","20190301","2019-03-01","shantnu kumar","20000","12","20000","Upward Term Loan","","","Indiabulls Consumer Finance Limited"},
    {"GOA473214","20190304","2019-03-04","KANNAN M KANNAN","25000","12","18000","Upward Term Loan","","","Gestamp Automotive Chennai Pvt Ltd"},
    {"GOA291263","20190308","2019-03-08","pavan guptha","50000","24","22000","Upward Term Loan","","","Hcl Technologies Limited"}
]
```

I have tried below solution

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($data as $obj)
{
    $new_array[] = (object)$obj;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

And

```
function ToObject($Array) { 

    // Create new stdClass object 
    $object = new stdClass(); 

    // Use loop to convert array into 
    // stdClass object 
    foreach ($Array as $key => $value) { 
        if (is_array($value)) { 
            $value = ToObject($value); 
        } 
        $object->$key = $value; 
    } 
    return $object; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
foreach($data as &$arr){
    $arr = json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}

print_r($data);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/7JpHU

Comment: @NishantNair  are you serious, array data without indexes? how's it will be possible.

Comment: Yes It's my requirement '

Comment: @NishantNair  can you show us the code where you want this data without indexes? May be we can help to rectify that code to meetup your requirement. Because an array if contains any data then index will present automatically. Only empty array cannot have any indexes.